# Geração de erro ao tentar criar um diretório usando o Python: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

Tags: python-3.x

Em uma vídeo aula que assisti, o professor usa o seguinte comando para criar um diretório usando o Python:

```
import os

res = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'geek')
os.chdir(res)
print(os.getcwd())
```

Literalmente, é só isso que ele faz. Como o diretório 'geek' não existe, esse comando o cria. Porém, ao executar exatamente o mesmo código aqui, é gerado o seguinte erro:

"**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PycharmProjects\Guppe\testes.py", line 4, in 
os.chdir(res)**

**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado: 'D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PycharmProjects\Guppe\geek'"**

Ou seja, no computador no professor da aula, o comando funcionou e criou o diretório "geek". Já aqui, é gerado esse erro. Gostaria de saber o motivo do erro, já que o código está exatamente igual.
Vale lembrar que no vídeo da aula é usado Ubuntu, enquanto eu uso Windows 10.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu código atual irá completar com sucesso caso o diretório *geek* exista, porém irá falhar caso não exista. O comando `os.chdir` não cria um diretório caso o mesmo não exista. Essa é função do comando `os.mkdir`:

```
import os

res = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'geek')
os.mkdir(res)
os.chdir(res)
print(os.getcwd())
```

O código acima irá completar com sucesso caso o diretório *geek* não exista, porém irá falhar caso exista. Para resolver esse problema, basta usar a função `os.path.isdir`:

```py
import os

res = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'geek')

# Verifica se a pasta já existe; caso não, a cria
if not os.path.isdir(res):
    os.mkdir(res)

os.chdir(res)
print(os.getcwd())
```

O código acima irá completar com sucesso, seja *geek* existindo ou não.

Comment: Entendi. Só acho estranho que, no caso do vídeo, o comando que cria o diretório é o `res = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'geek')`. O comando `os.chdir(res)`, pelo que entendi, só entraria no diretório após ele já ter sido criado, e o `os.mkdir(res)` não foi usado no vídeo. Porém, a vídeo aula é de 2018, então suponho que de lá pra cá devem ter alterado isso no Python, pois justamente por ser vídeo, dá pra ver o comando funcionando "em tempo real". Acredito que antes então era possível criar um diretório dessa forma, mas agora não deve ser.